# If $A\setminus B\subset C$, prove that $x\in A\setminus C$ implies $x\in B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets such that $A\setminus B\subset C$. Prove that if $x\in A\setminus C$, then $x\in B$.

Comment: With Proof by Contradiction . But How I can solve this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets such that $A \setminus B \subset C$.

First we see the symbol $ \setminus$ which is the symbol for set difference.
This basically means every element in $A$  that is not in $B$. This can be written as: 
$$\forall x[ x\in A : \neg( x\in B)]$$

Next we see the symbol $ \subset $ which is the symbol of subset. This means that every element of the set on the left hand side is also in the set on the right hand side. This can be written as:
$$\forall x[ x\in A \setminus B: x \in C]  $$

Now we need to prove the following:

> Prove that if $x \in A \setminus C$, then $x \in B$

We can rewrite this as:
$$\forall x[x \in A \setminus C \implies x \in B]$$

or

$$\forall x[x \in A \setminus C : x \in B]$$

*I will update the proof once I found a tool to construct to proof with. *
I will provide a temporary indication on the proof.

According to our definition of the sets  $A, B$ and $C$

We have $A \setminus B \subset C$. This is the same as
$$\forall x [x \in A \land  x \notin B : x \in C] $$

So when $x \notin B$, then $x \in A \land x \in C$

$\equiv$

$x \notin B \implies (x \in A \land x \in C)$

We can rewrite the part of $x$ both in $A$ and $B$ as $x \in A \cap B$, meaning the intersection of $A$ and $B$ (The elements both sets have in common).

Then we also have:
$x \in B \implies \neg (x \in A \cap B)$

Back to the statement.

> $x \in A \setminus C$

Since $A$ (we can leave the difference with B) is a subset, all elements of $A$ are also in C, by the definition of subset. Thus when we take the difference of $A$ and $C$ we get $\emptyset$, the empty set.

<s>Since $x \notin \emptyset$ it must be in $B$.</s>

So $x \in \emptyset$ and since $\emptyset \subset$ Any set,

$\emptyset \subset B$, Hence $x \in B$

*Update of proof

> Prove that if $x \in A \setminus C$, then $x \in B$

Proof: Suppose $x \in A \setminus C$

Since we know $A \setminus B \subset C$, we know that it must always hold for any arbitrary sets $A, B, C$. From this we can distinct two cases:

**Case: A = C or $A \subset C$**

When A = C then B must always be a set such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ in order for the proposition of the subset to always hold. Hence $x \in A \setminus C \equiv x \in \emptyset.$ Since we know that the $\emptyset \subset$ any arbitrary set it follows that also $\emptyset \subset B$. Hence since $x \in \emptyset$ then also $x \in B$. This proves that $x \in A \setminus C  \implies x \in B$

**Case: A = B or $A \subset B$**

When A = B then C can be any arbitrary set since $ A / B \equiv \emptyset$ and we know that the $\emptyset \subset$ of any arbitrary set. Hence we always have $\emptyset \subset C$.

Then $x \in A \setminus C$ always yields that $x \in \emptyset \equiv x \in A \equiv x \in B $. This proves that $x \in A \setminus C  \implies x \in B$

**Case: B = C**

When B = C then A must always be $\emptyset$ in order for the proposition  $A \setminus B \subset C$ to hold. Thus we have the same result described in the previous case which proves that $x \in A \setminus C  \implies x \in B$.

In all possible cases of $A,B,C$ that satisfy $A \setminus B \subset C$ we have proven that $x \in A \setminus C  \implies x \in B$

Answer (score 1):

So you have $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Suppose $x\notin B$. Then $x\in A\setminus B\subset C$, so $x\in C$, a contradiction. Therefore $x\in B$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't still understand x∈A∖B⊂C, so x∈C,

Comment: Well, if you assume that $x\notin B$, then you have $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$. But $A\setminus B$ is a subset of $C$, which means that $C$ contains $A\setminus B$ and hence also the element $x$. That is, $x\in C$.

Comment: When you are content with an answer, please upvote it and check.